# Bounce Effect on RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, bounce

I want to use a bounce effect on a `RecyclerView`. A bounce effect whenever I overscroll the content...

Does there exist a library or example for it?

Comment: Were you able to find one?

Comment: unfortunately not yet...

Comment: here i saw a lib named [Bounce](https://github.com/surahul/Bounce) may help you.

Answer (score 15):

I also couldn't find any library that supports the bounce effect for RecyclerView. Eventually I ended up implementing a new library by myself. Check out my library [overscroll-bouncy-android](https://github.com/chthai64/overscroll-bouncy-android). . It currently supports RecyclerView with LinearLayoutManager. I'm also working on ListView and ScrollView.

To use my library:

Step 1:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.chauthai.overscroll:overscroll-bouncy:0.1.0'
}
```

Step 2:

```
<com.chauthai.overscroll.RecyclerViewBouncy
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: I have RecyclerViewBouncy within SwipeRefreshLayout, and it looks like RecyclerViewBouncy swallows pull down event and refresh is not triggered

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work properly with CollapsingToolbarLayout

Answer (score 7):

This can be easily done with dynamic animations **without using any third-party library**.
I wrote an article about this [**here**](https://medium.com/mindorks/bounce-effect-in-recyclerview-6463a7f81e5?source=friends_link&sk=e2728a5580449a5f36c97e0152e94b42).

Another advantage is that it'll work with **any type of layout manager** and since we are using dynamic animations which are **physics-based** so animation feels more **natural**.

Comment: Is there any chance this is available in java?

Comment: tremendous work!

Comment: I followed you tutorial, it's great but a have a question, how will it work with multiple view holders?

Answer (score 4):

You can use this library https://github.com/EverythingMe/overscroll-decor
So, you need to create your own ScrollDecorAdapter like this

```
public class CustomRecyclerViewOverScrollDecorAdapter extends RecyclerViewOverScrollDecorAdapter {
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

public CustomRecyclerViewOverScrollDecorAdapter(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super(recyclerView);
    mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
}

@Override
public boolean isInAbsoluteEnd() {
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();
    if (linearLayoutManager.getOrientation() == LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL) {
        return !mRecyclerView.canScrollHorizontally(1);
    } else {
        return !mRecyclerView.canScrollVertically(1);
    }
  }
}
```

And now in your fragment/activity use

```
 CustomVerticalOverScrollDecorator overScrollDecorator =
            new CustomVerticalOverScrollDecorator(new CustomRecyclerViewOverScrollDecorAdapter(yourRecyclerView));
```

Where CustomVerticalOverScrollDecorator smth like this

```
public class CustomVerticalOverScrollDecorator extends VerticalOverScrollBounceEffectDecorator {

public CustomVerticalOverScrollDecorator(IOverScrollDecoratorAdapter viewAdapter) {
    this(viewAdapter, DEFAULT_TOUCH_DRAG_MOVE_RATIO_FWD, DEFAULT_TOUCH_DRAG_MOVE_RATIO_BCK, DEFAULT_DECELERATE_FACTOR);
}

public CustomVerticalOverScrollDecorator(IOverScrollDecoratorAdapter viewAdapter, float touchDragRatioFwd, float touchDragRatioBck, float decelerateFactor) {
    super(viewAdapter, touchDragRatioFwd, touchDragRatioBck, decelerateFactor);

    // Some setup on the view itself.
   }
  }
```

Comment: Tried both libraries(this and Chau Thai's). 
1. Chau's library is great but it only supports LinearLayoutManager and sometimes is a bit buggy when updating/adding new items.
2. overscroll-decor is great. The only drawback is that it does not support auto-over-scroll effect (when you fling and it reaches top/bottom). Chau's library supports it. (https://github.com/EverythingMe/overscroll-decor/issues/1)

Answer (score 3):

You can try my library https://github.com/Valkriaine/Bouncy.

It supports both recyclerview and nestedscrollview.

Add it in your root build.gradle at the end of repositories:

```
allprojects {
      repositories {
          ...
          maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
      }
  }
```

In your app module build.gradle:

```
     dependencies {
        implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
        implementation 'com.github.valkriaine:Bouncy:2.2'
   }
```

And use it as a normal recyclerview.

```
<com.factor.bouncy.BouncyRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:recyclerview_fling_animation_size=".7"
        app:recyclerview_overscroll_animation_size=".7"
        app:recyclerview_damping_ratio="DAMPING_RATIO_LOW_BOUNCY"
        app:recyclerview_stiffness="STIFFNESS_MEDIUM"
        app:allow_drag_reorder="true"
        app:allow_item_swipe="false"/>
```

Setup adapter and layoutmanager. Technically supports any layoutmanager:

```xml
   recycler_view.setAdapter(myAdapter);
   recycler_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
   //recycler_view.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, 3));
```

Horizontal overscroll too:

```java
recycler_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
```

If the bounce animation is in the wrong direction (eg bouncing horizontally while the layout is vertical) you can also manually set the animation orientation:

```java
 recycler_view.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
```