# Bounce scrolling effect in RecycleView

Tags: android-recyclerview, scrollview, android-animation

I want to implement bounce animation effect on android recycleview.
how can I do that?

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you actually researched something? Filling in google "recyclerview bounce effect" would land you to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31632542/bounce-effect-on-recyclerview) answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bounce Effect on RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31632542/bounce-effect-on-recyclerview)

Comment: thank you @azizbekian
can u help me?how to implement like this library
 **'com.chauthai.overscroll:overscroll-bouncy:0.1.0'**
in my custom RecycleView Class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `RecyclerView` with `RecyclerViewBouncy`.

Add dependency:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.chauthai.overscroll:overscroll-bouncy:0.1.0'
}
```

In layout:

```
<com.chauthai.overscroll.RecyclerViewBouncy .../>
```

You can only use `LinearLayoutManager`